# python receives absolute video URI path but can't acess/read video file

Tags: android, opencv, video-processing, chaquopy

I'm developing a program that gets a video from Android Storage and converts it to a uint8 array.

For that, I'm gettint the video URI path and passing it to a python script that performs the frames processing in turning frames into uint8 matrix elements. I'm using most recent version of chaquopy.

I was able to get the absolute and relative URI path of the video (that can be choosen by the user) and pass it to the python function.

However, it seems the python function is not being able to acess the video and process the frames.

Does anyone knows how do I fix this?

\ MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int REQUEST_PICK_VIDEO = 101;
    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 101;
    private static final String TAG = "APP_TAG";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Start the process of picking a video from the gallery
        if (checkPermission()) {
            pickVideo();
        }
    }

    private void pickVideo() {
        // Start the video picker activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        intent.setDataAndType(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "video/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PICK_VIDEO);
        intent.setType("video/*");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PICK_VIDEO && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            Uri videoUri = data.getData();
            Log.d(TAG,"Not real URI is: "+ videoUri);

            // Pass the selected video Uri to the VideoProcessor
            VideoProcessor.processVideo(this, videoUri);

            // Access the processed frames as a list of byte arrays
            List<byte[]> processedFrames = VideoProcessor.getProcessedFrames();

            // Check if the list is not null and not empty
            if (processedFrames != null && !processedFrames.isEmpty()) {
                Log.d("VideoProcessor", "Number of processed frames: " + processedFrames.size());
            } else {
                // Handle the case when the processedFrames list is empty or null
                Log.e("VideoProcessor", "No processed frames available.");
                Toast.makeText(this, "No processed frames available.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            // Handling for canceled or failed video picking
            Toast.makeText(this, "Video picking canceled or failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    // Check for READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission and request it if necessary
    private boolean checkPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    REQUEST_PERMISSION_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


}
```

\ VideoProcessor class

```
public class VideoProcessor {

    private static final String TAG = "APP_TAG";
    private static List<byte[]> processedFrames;

    public VideoProcessor() {
        processedFrames = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public static void processVideo(Context context, Uri videoUri) {
        Python py = Python.getInstance();
        if (!Python.isStarted()) {
            Python.start(new AndroidPlatform(context));
        }

        // Convert videoUri to a String representation of the file path
        String videoPath = getRealPathFromUri(context, videoUri);
        Log.d(TAG, "Real URI path is:" + videoPath);

        PyObject videoProcessingModule = py.getModule("script");

        // Call the process_video function in the Python script and pass the video file path as a parameter
        PyObject processedData = videoProcessingModule.callAttr("process_video", videoPath);

        // Get the processed data as a 2D NumPy array (assuming video_processing.py returns a 2D array)
        PyObject[] processedFramesArray = processedData.toJava(PyObject[].class);

        // Convert PyObject[] to List<byte[]>
        for (PyObject frame : processedFramesArray) {
            processedFrames.add(frame.toJava(byte[].class));
        }
    }

    public static List<byte[]> getProcessedFrames() {
        return processedFrames;
    }

    // get the real file path from a content Uri
    private static String getRealPathFromUri(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
        String realPath = null;
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA};

        try (Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, projection, null, null)) {
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
                realPath = cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return realPath;
    }
}
```

\ Python script

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os

def process_video(video_path):
    print("Received video path:", video_path)

    # Check if the file exists
    if not os.path.exists(video_path):
        print("Error: Video file does not exist.")
        return []

    # Check if the file is readable
    if not os.access(video_path, os.R_OK):
        print("Error: Video file is not readable.")
        return []

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

    frames = []
    while cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            break
        # Process the frame (example: convert it to grayscale)
        processed_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        frames.append(processed_frame)

    cap.release()

    print("Number of processed frames:", len(frames))

    # Return the frames as a list of 1D byte arrays
    return [frame.tobytes() for frame in frames]
```

\ Output after choosing a video

```
2023-08-02 17:26:07.587  3729-3729  python.stdout           com.example.a07312023                I  Received video path: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyCameraApp/VID_20230416_204625.mp4
2023-08-02 17:26:07.587  3729-3729  python.stdout           com.example.a07312023                I  Error: Video file is not readable.
2023-08-02 17:26:07.590  3729-3729  VideoProcessor          com.example.a07312023                E  No processed frames available.
```

Comment: `getRealPathFromUri` will never, ever work. You only have access to that content via its Uri - you need to use those APIs to open an InputStream directly, rather than trying to make it into a file that you will not have access to.

Comment: Hi ian, sorry to ask but what do you mean by " will never, ever work" ? Because it is giving the absolute path as output. Do I have to first pass the video as an InputStream to then send it to python?

Answer (score 2):

> Because it is giving the absolute path as output.

You have no guarantee of that, as there are many valid responses to `ACTION_PICK` where that code will fail miserably. And, even if you do wind up with a filesystem path, you may not have read access to the contents via filesystem APIs.

> Do I have to first pass the video as an InputStream to then send it to python?

If somebody is forcing you at gunpoint to use Python, you will probably need to use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream` in your Java code to get an `InputStream`, use that stream to copy the content to some file that you control, and then use that file with your Python code. If your Python environment happens to be able to work with `InputStream` directly, that probably would perform better.